# Enable service_url in ejabberd using mod_http_upload

Tags: ejabberd, ejabberd-module

I'm using ejabberd 15.09 and mod_http_upload.
According to `https://github.com/weiss/mod_http_upload` , if `service_url` is defined then, upload service should be forwarded to the given link.
However, even though I have define the `service_url` link, it still reverts to `put_url`.
How do I configure mod_http_upload to use `service_url` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause could be the mod_http_upload read its own conf file instead of your ejabberd.yml.

The mod_http_upload conf file can be found under ejabberd_folder_home/.ejabberd-modules/mode_http_upload/conf

You can delete this file and mod_http_upload will read your ejabberd.yml.

Source: https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/issues/122